# Spring Data Pagination works incorect

Tags: java, spring-boot, pagination, spring-data

I'm trying to get data from my repository using pagination and i get weird results.

Contoroller code:

```
@GetMapping("/warehouses")
@Cacheable(value = "warehouses")
public List<Warehouse> findWarehouses(@RequestParam(name = "page", required = false, defaultValue = "1") int page,
                                      @RequestParam(name = "size", required = false, defaultValue = "10") int size) {
    return warehouseRepository.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, size)).getContent();
}
```

Repository uses default MongoRepository method.

I'm sending requests and getting next result. [1st query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhFn6.png) [2nd query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el0aV.png) [3rd query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jwdD.png) [4th query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/za07l.png) [5th query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9IFM.png) [6th query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxVMt.png)

This is my stored data in db

```
[
  {
    _id: 'Compluter Inc',
    merchandiseQuantity: { computer: 16, vacine: 10, bebra: 6 },
    position: { x: 43, y: 12 },
    _class: 'com.logistic.project.model.Warehouse'
  },
  {
    _id: 'Bebra',
    merchandiseQuantity: { grivna: 20, laptop: 100, beer: 1 },
    position: { x: 21, y: 89 },
    _class: 'com.logistic.project.model.Warehouse'
  },
  {
    _id: 'LG',
    merchandiseQuantity: { chair: 90, cup: 13, notebook: 18 },
    position: { x: 15, y: 90 },
    _class: 'com.logistic.project.model.Warehouse'
  },
  {
    _id: 'Abchihba',
    merchandiseQuantity: { gun: 54, computer: 4, answer: 42 },
    position: { x: 567, y: 890 },
    _class: 'com.logistic.project.model.Warehouse'
  },
  {
    _id: 'Node',
    merchandiseQuantity: { grinva: 6, gun: 16, charger: 132 },
    position: { x: 389, y: 54 },
    _class: 'com.logistic.project.model.Warehouse'
  },
  {
    _id: 'Meta',
    merchandiseQuantity: { computer: 16, vacine: 10, bebra: 6 },
    position: { x: 321, y: 590 },
    _class: 'com.logistic.project.model.Warehouse'
  } 
]
```

Thanks for answers)

Comment: Also i tried to delete @Cacheable and got same result.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem i forgot that pagination starts from 0